# Django raw query with WHERE clause generated from previous query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I want to do a Django Python MySQL query with `WHERE` (in sql) being a link generated from a previous query.
Hereby I paste my actual code:

```
def population(request):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='xxxx', db='xxxxdb', passwd='xxxxpwd', host='localhost')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT last_name FROM a_population WHERE country='Denmark' ORDER BY last_name")
    denominazione_comune = cursor.fetchall();
    rows_count = cursor.rowcount
    db.close()
    counter = 0

    return render_to_response('list_last_name.html', {'lastname': last_name}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So from this code I get an (un)ordered list of family names. By clicking one of these family names I would like to create another query with the family name clicked as a parameter but I don't have a clue of how to do that.

Thanks a million to whom will give me some input.

Comment: can you please give a more sensible title?

Comment: what you want from raw sql that you cant implement with ORM?

Comment: Ok, did change the title (thanks to ansh0l).

Comment: What does `(un)ordered` mean, and in what sense is this `ordered` result `unordered`?

Comment: Means it makes no difference if we deal with an ordered or unordered list.